# Connection is Using Properly or not in Net Use via SQL Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, windows, xp-cmdshell

am doing an operation of creating a file and writing in a SAN SAMBA where it will be done using the cmd_shell via SQL Procedure. It's creating and writing it successfully but while am calling that procedure 2 two times at the same time am getting the issue as

> The local device name is already in use.

Is there any options while using this net use command I have 15 different procedures each will be having this type of behavior.

Note: Every Procedure is given a Drive name differently.

> EXEC xp_cmdshell  'net use r: \10.44.11.44\dpsshare Password
>   /user:Username /persistent:no'

Am also deleting the Network Connection at the end of the Procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Your NET USE command tells Windows - not just SQL Server - to map a network drive to a letter. When it runs, it makes that drive letter available to the SQL Server process, where it can be used for all connections.

A lot of things in SQL Server are per-connection - like creating a temp table - but what you're doing, mapping a network drive to a letter, is for the entire SQL Server process.

**Your first thought might be, "Oh, so I need to check to see if the folder is mapped first** - like use xp_dirtree to get the directory contents. If the folder is already mapped, then I can skip that NET USE step."

Unfortunately, that won't work either.

Because you mentioned at the end of your procedures, you're un-mapping those drives. That means you can run into this situation:

1. Instance A of the stored proc starts, checks to see if the drive is mapped. It isn't, so it maps the drive, and starts working.
2. Instance B of the stored proc starts, checks to see if the drive is mapped. It IS already mapped, so it just starts working without creating the drive mapping.
3. Instance A finishes up, and unmaps the drive.
4. Instance B was still running - but it now can no longer write to the drive. It fails.

**So how do you work around it?** Don't map drive letters. Access folders by their UNC path instead, like \\10.44.11.44\dpsshare. Grant the necessary permissions to the SQL Server's account rather than hard-coding usernames and passwords inside your application code. (Security is a much bigger discussion too - I get nervous when I see you exposing passwords in your code, and I also get nervous about SQL Server being able to write to a remote file share. You're in an area where application servers are a much better fit.)

Comment: Actually, am not keeping the password hard-coded, am taking it from the table which will AES Encrypted. (Access folders by their UNC path instead) how can I do this in SQL Procedure? @Brent

Comment: @ManuCRajan as I wrote in the answer, I would not recommend doing it with NET USE. I would use UNC paths to eliminate the concurrency problem.